# Specify a height constraints in code

Tags: objective-c, height, autolayout

I want to specify a fixed NSView height in code. With the method `addConstraint:` I can specify relation between object property but I can' t say:"This NSView should be 50 pixel high". Anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

whatabout:

```
[myView addConstraint:
    [NSLayoutConstraint
        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(50)]"
                                options:0
                                metrics:nil
                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)
    ]
];
```

but remember, you now have only added a constraint to the view. You will probably want to have it in some kind of controller, related to other objects. It is perfectly fine to have views to set their own constraints. That is what happens in InterfaceBuilder all the time. The relation between other views and elements of the UI should be in the next higher level in the view tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like visual constraint format you can also set like this.

```
    var heightCosntraint    = NSLayoutConstraint(item: seperationView,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
    toItem: nil, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, 
    multiplier: 1, 
    constant: 5.0)

    seperationView.addConstraint(heightCosntraint)
```